# Cannot boot from usb

Tags: boot, usb

I bought a new computer (Samsung NP900X4D) which came with Windows 8.
I want to install linux (Mint 14) but the computer lacks any optical drives, and so the only option (I'm aware of) is using a bootable usb.

I created it using UNetbootin from the ISO I downloaded from the official web site and I changed the priority of the boot.
The usb is not being recognized and so the windows loader starts up.

I tried to install mint from within windows which seemed ok, but once I rebooted I received an error when booting from mint.
I tried to remove the installation and try again but now I can't even load windows and I get an error message with only the option to go back to the UEFI firmware settings.

I tried different usb sticks, on different ports but to no avail, it's always being unrecognized.
I tried to use the stick on a different computer and it recognized the stick and loaded the installation, so it's not a problem with the stick.

Also, I'm pretty sure that the first time I tried the stick was recognized, and when I booted through it and selected to run mint it just got stuck, and then I rebooted and the stick is ignored ever since.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried booting the USB stick on a different computer?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that. I did try it and the other computer recognized the stick. I'll edit my question with this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of steps that you should experiment with:

- Disable Secure Boot in the UEFI interface
- Check which mode you are booting in: UEFI, Compatibility or Legacy (you will likely only be able to, initially, use Compatibility or Legacy mode).
- Make sure Fastboot is disabled in the UEFI interface
- Ensure that the USB drive has highest priority in the boot order
- If that machine has USB 2 and 3 drives, use the USB 2 port

All of these steps are necessary, in my experience, but may not be sufficient conditions to boot successfully from USB on the Samsung Series 9 machines.

Lastly, I am wary of bootable drives created with UNetbootin, I much prefer `dd`.

Comment: It worked! I'm not sure which part exactly.. it uses the UNetbootin version (though I made one using dd as well, thanks for that, learned a new command) and in the usb 3 port, but I disabled the secure boot and the fastboot and I disabled the harddrive in the boot devices, that did the trick.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Did you see your bootable USB flash drive in UEFI [Boot Menu](http://s1.postimg.org/pxw1zdqkf/20150816_123902.jpg)? For some reason I have only "Windows Boot Manager" there.